# Protecting mysql instance on Linux Azure VM

Tags: mysql, security, azure

I have mysql running in a Linux Azure VM. It's currently bound to the "Internal IP Address" of the VM as looked up in `ifconfig` and the Azure Dashboard. I've turned on logging to see who and what is connecting to mysql after noticing performance issues. What I've found is a huge amount of spam from Chinese IP addresses attempting to brute force in to the database.

It's a lot of this:

`Access denied for user 'mysql'@'blahblah' (using password: YES)`

As far as I am aware, there are no intrusions, just a lot of failed login attempts. How can I restrict this so that only IPs internal to Azure can even see the database so I don't have these connections in the first place?

Comment: Are you connecting to your MySQL server using the DIP or VIP? Not entirely clear from the description. If you do not connect through the VIP, just don't create a private to public port mapping in your endpoints to prevent anyone on the internet from accessing your server.

Comment: @proteus by "internal IP address", I meant the DIP. However, I've noticed that this isn't entirely dedicated as it can change when the VM is restarted.

Comment: @proteus also removing the public endpoint causes the database to be unreachable by my Azure WebSites instance

Comment: Oh OK, you are using Azure Websites. That won't allow you to be in the same VNET and use the DIP. As suggested below, firewalling access should work for blocking majority of the bad traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure ACL for your external endpoint.

Navigate to Virtual Machines >> Select VM >> Endpoints tab >> Select MySQL Endpoint >> Manage ACL >> Add ips (both private and public).

For a single ip add /32 after address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32. After all permit rules, add a deny rule to 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

If You want that MySQL listen only to localhost edit the MySQL configuration file:

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I need connections from beyond the localhost since Azure WebSites isn't hosted on the same VM and requires a connection. However, it is housed in the same Azure Data Center (East US 2).

Comment: if you access DB from only a single host, you can create an iptables rule to reject from everything else. Another option is to create a tunnel - for example through ssh

Comment: I might be able to accept only 191.238.* ip addresses since that seems to be the subnet that Azure WebSites originates from (in the data center I'm using)